# How to prevent bash subshell from waiting for child process

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that among other things, launches a background process. I use a function that setups some configuration for the process, launches it, checks it started correctly, and returns its PID, which is used later to kill the subprocess. The sample code below has the same structure but simplified logic:

```
function launcher(){
    sleep 30 &
    echo $!


PID=$(launcher)
echo $PID
kill $PID
```

The issue I'm facing is that the subshell that executes the `launcher` function does not return until the `sleep` command ends. Therefore the `echo $PID` statement is not executed until the subshell ends.

what surprises me is that if I check the `sleep` command, it does not have the script as parent id:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD
user     20135     1  0 18:39 pts/8    S+     0:00 sleep 30
```

How can I start the `sleep &` in the background to allow the subshell to end before it ends?

**Note**: Please notice in my case, the background process will never end until I kill it, so I need the subshell to end get the PID. Also notice in my real code, the logic of the `launcher` function is quite complex and I'm running it as a subshell to isolate the main process from it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens that the problem was about `stdin` because the main shell was reading from the subshell's `stdout`, which is inherited by the background process. Just redirecting the `stdout` when invoking the background process makes it work as expected.

```
sleep 100 > /dev/null &
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this gets it done but

```
function launcher(){
    echo "start launching"
    sleep 100  &
    echo "end launching"
}

launcher
PID=$!

# Here $PID is the process id of `sleep`
echo $PID
kill $PID
```

Without the `kill`, this runs the `sleep` command forked and the shell script ends leaving the `sleep` command running with the pid set in `PID` which means you could kill it later or not.

Is this what you need?  If not, can you clarify what you're expecting?

I also noticed that if the parent script stays alive, the PPID of the sleep process is correct and stays in tact.

```
# sleeper_test.sh
#!/bin/bash
function launcher(){
    echo "start launching"
    sleep 100  &
    echo "end launching"
}

launcher
PID=$!

# Here $PID is the process id of `sleep`
echo $PID

sleep 10
#kill $PID
```

```
$ ps -ef | grep sleep
  501 13748  5471   0  1:54PM ttys000    0:00.00 /bin/bash ./sleeper_test.sh
  501 13749 13748   0  1:54PM ttys000    0:00.00 sleep 100 <- child correctly tied to the parent sh script
  501 13750 13748   0  1:54PM ttys000    0:00.00 sleep 10
$ ps -ef | grep sleep
  501 13749     1   0  1:54PM ttys000    0:00.00 sleep 100 <- since the parent ended - it's parent becomes the root process parent
``
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer @mr-rogers. But as I mentioned in the question, the idea of having a subshell was also for isolation, so calling the launcher function directly doesn't really work for my scenario.